# Working with list in R

Tags: json, r, list

i have in R a lot of lists like this:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$long_name
[1] "Ħal Għaxaq"

[[1]]$short_name
[1] "Ħal Għaxaq"

[[1]]$types
[1] "locality"  "political"


[[2]]
[[2]]$long_name
[1] "Malta"

[[2]]$short_name
[1] "MT"

[[2]]$types
[1] "country"   "political"
```

Sometimes the lists have more than 2 elements. For each list I need to "read" only $long_name of the element in the list that has in $types "country"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data <- list(list(long_name = "Hal Ghaxaq", 
                  short_name = "Hal Ghaxaq", 
                  types = c("locality", "political")), 
             list(long_name = "Malta", 
                  short_name = "MT", 
                  types = c("country", "political")))
result <- data[ sapply(data, function(el) "country" %in% el$types)]
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch, I find very hard working with listS in R, you saved my life